# i define one variable(VOTING_ALLOWED) in init.php file but i did not get value in other page

Tags: php

whenever change the `VOTING_ALLOWED` value in the `init.php` file but I did not get in `single.php` please help me.

**init.php**

```php
$votingSettings = get_option( 'voting_settings' );

$allowVoting = false;

if($votingSettings && is_array($votingSettings)) {

    $allowVoting = strtoupper($votingSettings["is_voting_allowed"]) == "YES";
    $onlyForLoggedIn = strtoupper($votingSettings["only_logged_in"]) == "YES";

    $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();
    $isUserLoggedIn =  0 != $currentUser->ID;   

if(!$isUserLoggedIn && $onlyForLoggedIn) {

        $allowVoting = false;
    }

}

if(!defined('VOTING_ALLOWED')) {

    define('VOTING_ALLOWED', $allowVoting);

}
```

**single.php**

```php
var_dump(VOTING_ALLOWED);
```

Comment: Have you included the init.php in single.php? Secondly, `define()` is used for defining constant which means its value should not be changed once defined. You should consider changing it to simple variable only.

Comment: yes I included init.php in single.php i don't get Votting_alloed value in single.php on time